# How to lowercase the month name with strftime

Tags: python, c, strftime

In [strftime](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) `%b` is the month name

```
>>> '{:%b}'.format(datetime.now())
'Apr'
```

I can uppercase it using chinese-hat modifier carrot thing

```
>>> '{:%^b}'.format(datetime.now())
'APR'
```

How do I lowercase it?  i.e. to get the result `'{:%b}'.format(dt).lower()`, but using the template rather than a post-processing step.

Comment: There appears to be no such option, quite simply.

Comment: Sorry, I thought your description of the `^` caret was rather off-hand and insulting. But you changed it back.

Comment: I'm not sure what's offensive about that.  Yes I changed it back because excessive political-correctness annoys me

Comment: I only changed it to its correct name, which a 64-k rep commenter should have known. Have you ever seen a Chinese wearing a "coolie hat"? That's so stereotypical 19th century - I'll leave the politics to you.

Answer (score 7):

Just add `.lower()` after `datetime.now()`. As far as I know there is no other way to do it.

Comment: "I don't know" is never a valid answer.

Comment: I mean that as far as i know there are no ways to do it. But a man can always be wrong in my opinion. But it is better to don't say that here? (i'm new here so don't know. Just being honest. Appreciate the feedback)

Comment: @makaveli - The answer does not consist solely of _I don't know_; you should not blindly react to certain key phrases, but rather read context.

Comment: @wanaryytel Complete fine in this case, your comment is useless.